# Script for autologin in the lockscrren

Tags: windows-10

i like the image in the lockscreen but i don't always want to type my password/pin.
i thought of a vbs script similar to this one i wrote:
it's just a test I don't even know if a vbs script can write in the lockscreen login box

set o =Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
o.Run "notepad"
o.SendKeys "password"
o.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

Now i need replace notepad with the combination win+l but how?
it's just a test I don't even know if a vbs script can write in the lockscreen login box ...

Answer (score 0):

No running program can affect the Lock Screen, so VBS or anything similar
won't work.

The best is to use your phone to lock and unlock the computer automatically.
To turn on this option:

- Use Bluetooth to pair your phone with your PC
- On the PC, select the *Start > Settings  > Accounts > Sign-in options*
- Under Dynamic lock, select "Allow Windows to automatically lock your device when you're away check box".

For more information see:

- Microsoft's
  [Lock your Windows 10 PC automatically when you step away from it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/lock-your-windows-10-pc-automatically-when-you-step-away-from-it-d0a5f536-74ac-0859-820a-4140dac9fcaf)
- Detailed tutorial in
  [How To Use Your Phone To Lock And Unlock Windows 10](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-use-phone-lock-unlock-windows-10,36775.html)

Comment: Isn't possible a change inthe registry?

Comment: No, the lock screen is an obvious critical security element for Windows, so it's well isolated and protected. One is obliged to use the mechanisms provided by Microsoft. So your options are: 1. No password, 2. Phone unlock, 3. Face recognition unlock, 4. USB key unlock, 5. PIN number (shorter than password). No other options (for the moment).